# How can I install my bower dependencies on a deployed Heroku app?

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment

I'll try to simplify this problem down:

I am deploying an application using Heroku, and I would like to automatically install my bower dependencies. When testing on a localhost, I would just run a "bower install" command in the terminal, but I am not sure how to translate this over to a deployed application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ll need to install Bower as a dependency to your app in package.json.

```
npm install --save bower
```

You will then need to add a post install script in package.json with the path to your bower dependency inside node_modules, it should look like this

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
}
```

After the npm package is installed by Heroku, this script will be executed and your bower dependencies will be automatically installed!

I wrote a blog post about this not too long ago actually that goes into a little bit more detail:
http://www.catherinebui.com/post/105338527207/deploying-node-js-app-on-heroku-with-bower#105338527207

Comment: Note that you just need `bower install`, as npm places any executable files defined in package.json into the path when running scripts.